# Java: Storing Values in Multiple Arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist

I think that I have a rather simple question, but I can't figure out how i am supposed to do it. I have created one multiple arraylist, where I want to store some data from an array.
I want to check which entries are the same.

For example, if array[0] = array[5] = array[8] but array[1] is not equal to any entry, and array[2] = array[3]

I would like to have for the arraylist look like

array2[0] | array2[5] | array2[8]

array2[2] | array2[3]

```
 List<String> dup_non = new ArrayList<String>(), dn = new ArrayList <String>(); 

 for (int m = 0; m < array.length ; m++) 
    { 
        for(int o = m + 1; o < array.length; o++)         
        {   
              if (array[m].equals(array[o] && m!=o)){
                      dup_non.add(array2[m])
                      dn.add(array2[m],array2[o])
                               }
                          else { ....
                               } 
         }
     }
```

This code is what i was thinking more or less, since my array2 has unique elements, but it is not correct. It is correct, because array2 is not an array of integers.

If you have any idea, I would appreciate if you could share it.

Regards.

Comment: I can't figure out what it is you want to do here. In your example you reference 'array' and 'array2' but you define 'dup_non' and 'dn'. Do you want to check two arrays for duplicate values?

Comment: Well, I want to check if array has duplicate values and store array2, which has unique elements, in the arraylist. I am sorry if I confused you, but I am working in a more complex program, that is why I am trying to present as simple as possible.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. I have really tried to explain my problem, giving examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Please check following program for your requirement

    I have created HashMap where Key as the your values that will duplicate and ArrayList as List of value duplicated  


    import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class Dog {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer,List<Integer>> hashMap=new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
         int array[]={1,1,1,2,2,2,4,3,3,3};


         for (int m = 0; m < array.length ; m++) {
             System.out.print(array[m]);
             List<Integer> dup=(List<Integer>)hashMap.get(array[m]);
             if(dup==null){

                 dup=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                 hashMap.put(array[m],dup);
                 dup.add(array[m]);

             }else{
                 dup.add(array[m]);
             }
         }

         Set<Entry<Integer, List<Integer>>> keys = hashMap.entrySet();
         for (Iterator iterator = keys.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry = (Entry<Integer, List<Integer>>) iterator.next();
            List<Integer> arrayList = entry.getValue();
            if(arrayList.size()==1)
                hashMap.put(entry.getKey(), null);
        }


         System.out.print(hashMap.get(1));
         System.out.print(hashMap.get(2));
         System.out.print(hashMap.get(3));
         System.out.print(hashMap.get(4));
    }
}
```

Comment: You suggest to use a multiple hashmap to make it work. The line if(dup==null) is used to check if the hashmap "row" is empty, right?

Comment: yes you are right , the line if(dup==null) is used to check if hash-map value is null for that particular key.

Comment: The only problem is that if my array is like int array[]={1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5}; the result is 1112223334555[1, 1, 1][2, 2, 2][3, 3, 3][4][5, 5, 5] and I would like to omit from the hashmap the [4], which doesn't have a duplicate.

Comment: I have change program for your requirement please check, Hope this will be helpful.